# How to detect unicode file names in Linux

Tags: c++, unicode

I have a windows application written in C++. In this we used to check a file name is unicode or not using the wcstombs() function. If the conversion fails, we assume that it is unicode file name. Likewise when i tried the same in Linux, the conversion doesn't fail. I know in windows, the default charset is LATIN whereas the default charset of Linux is UTF8. Based on whether file name is unicode or not, we have different set of codings. Since I couldn't figure it out in Linux, I can't make my application portable for Unicode characters. Is there any other work around for this or am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: What do you even mean by "is Unicode"? That it contains non-ASCII character?

Comment: Your Windows method seems very strange. Well, the Windows way of dealing with Unicode is known to be brain-dead, but still. That aside, it is not clear what are you trying to achieve by looking at the filename. If you want to display the name, just do it according to the current locale. If you want to look at the content, just ignore the filename completely. Either way you don't need to analyze the name in any way.

Comment: The Windows idea really is wrong. `wctombs` can create multi-byte sequences, that's why it's named `...mb..`. It does depend on local settings; you can't just assume "LATIN".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

utf-8 has the nice property that all ascii characters are represented as in ascii, and all non-ascii characters are represented as sequences of [two or more bytes >=128](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). so all you have to check for ascii is the numerical magnitude of unsigned byte. if >=128, then non-ascii, which with utf-8 as the basic encoding means "unicode" (even if within range of latin-1, and note that latin-1 is a proper subset of unicode, constituting the first 256 code points).

---

howevever, note that while in Windows a filename is a *sequence of characters*, in *nix it is a *sequence of bytes*.

and so ideally you should really ignore what those bytes might encode.

might be difficult to reconcile with naïve user’s view, though

Comment: On Windows, it's not truly a sequence of characters either. You're quite free to use unpaired surrogates (half a character). You can't assume casing rules either, they're file-system specific.

Comment: @MSalters: thanks, i didn't know that. microsoft's ways are indeed mysterious!